# How to use an ALIAS in a PostgreSQL ORDER BY clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-8.1

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    title, 
    (stock_one + stock_two) AS global_stock
FROM
    product
ORDER BY
    global_stock = 0,
    title;
```

Running it in PostgreSQL 8.1.23 i get this error:

**Query failed: ERROR: column "global_stock" does not exist**

Anybody can help me to put it to work? I need the availale items first, after them the unnavailable items. Many thanks!

Comment: Postgres ***8.1***? You should upgrade **now**!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I am trying, my host has only this version at now. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Then you should change your host. 8.1 has been out of support for over 2 years now.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I will try, by the way, do you have a suggestion of a good host with a Postgres updated? Now i am using [Bounceweb (Brazil)](http://www.bounceweb.com.br/)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can always `ORDER BY` this way:

```
select 
    title, 
    ( stock_one + stock_two ) as global_stock
from product
order by 2, 1
```

or wrap it in another SELECT:

```
SELECT *
from
(
    select 
        title, 
        ( stock_one + stock_two ) as global_stock
    from product
) x
order by (case when global_stock = 0 then 1 else 0 end) desc, title
```

Comment: You saved my day! I've used the first option, it will be easier to me! Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you tell me please if the second option is much slower than the first one? I am having a problem with the pagination using the first solution, because i am using the LIMIT clause.

Comment: Dirty trick (the order by 2,1)

but if it works, it works :) thanks a ton

Comment: @Noobgrammer Yuck, this is a really old answer and I wouldn't suggest to `order by 2, 1` any longer. :)

Comment: @bluefeet what do you suggest instead?

Comment: @felixfbecker What are you talking about?

Comment: Would doing `ORDER BY COALESCE(2, 1)` according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20028142/242933) work?

Comment: @mattdipasquale You'd probably need to test it as I'm not sure offhand. I'll try to test it tomorrow if I can get my hands on a server to test on.

Comment: @bluefeet OK. Thank you. I don't think it'd work anyway. I think `COALESCE(2, 1)` would always evaluate to `2`, making it equivalent to `ORDER BY 2`. Anyway, never mind. In my case, I think it actually works better to just add `COALESCE(MAX(c.created), p.created) AS posted_at` to the list of columns after `SELECT` and then `ORDER BY posted_at DESC`.

Comment: @taryn Thanks! I need to do ORDER BY LOWER(2), but PostGres does not seem to interpret the 2 as a column position when it is passed to a function like this, just interprets as integer 2. Any ideas how to force it to? I realize I could add LOWER(exp) to the SELECT clause, but changing the SELECT clause is undesired in my use case.

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to use the position:

```
select  title, 
        ( stock_one + stock_two ) as global_stock
from product
order by 2, 1
```

However, the alias should work, but not necessarily the expression.  What do you mean by "global_stock = 0"?  Do you mean the following:

```
select  title, 
        ( stock_one + stock_two ) as global_stock
from product
order by (case when global_stock = 0 then 1 else 0 end) desc, title
```

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone finds this when googling for whether you can just `ORDER BY my_alias`: Yes, you can. This cost me a couple hours.

As the [postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY) state:

> The ordinal number refers to the ordinal (left-to-right) position of the output column. This feature makes it possible to define an ordering on the basis of a column that does not have a unique name. This is never absolutely necessary because it is always possible to assign a name to an output column using the `AS` clause.

So either this has been fixed since, or this question is specifically about the `ORDER BY my_alias = 0, other_column` syntax which I didn't actually need.