# MySQL order posts by most recent comment OR last posted

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

**How can I sort posts so most recent activity is on top?**

```
# Schema not including all info, including FKs
CREATE TABLE post(
   id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
   msg text,
   created datetime
)ENGINE=InnoDb;

CREATE TABLE comment(
   id int unsigned primary key auto_increment,
   post_id int unsigned,
   msg text,
   created datetime
)ENGINE=InnoDb;
```

I want to order posts by most recent, where a new post is obviously more recent than one previously posted, but an old post that has a recent comment associated with it qualifies as more recent still.

**1st attempt**

```
# Selecting '*' for simplicity in this example
select *
from post p
left join comment c on c.post_id = p.id
group by p.id
order by c.created desc, p.created desc
```

This doesn't work because new posts are sorted after old posts with comments.

**2nd attempt**

```
select *, if(c.id is null, p.created, c.created) as recency
from post p
left join comment c on c.post_id = p.id
group by p.id
order by recency desc
```

Doesn't work because if a post has more than one comment, *recency* will have the *created* value of the first row matched, which is the oldest comment.

**Is there a way to* group by p.id (so only one copy of each post is selected), but the sorting within each group is by c.date desc, but the query order by is done by recency? I can't think of a way to do that without possibly adding a *updated* field to *post*, which I'd write to whenever a reply is posted...

Thanks!

Comment: Although not reserved, `comment` is a recognised keyword in MySQL, so I'd be a little wary of using it as a table/column identifier

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM post p
    LEFT JOIN comment c on c.post_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY COALESCE(GREATEST(p.created, MAX(c.created)), p.created) DESC
```

If we assume that a comment is always older than the post, we can simplify:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM post p
    LEFT JOIN comment c on c.post_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY COALESCE(MAX(c.created), p.created) DESC
```

Comment: Kind of works, but in reverse order - which is solved by adding a DESC at the end of that query. Still, doesn't quite work.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks! I was not familiar with the COALESCE function. Thanks again!!

Comment: This worked perfectly for my exact situation. Thank you so much! I learned something new tonight.