# LEFT JOIN show duplicate matches

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

When I left-join these two tables 'posts' and 'comments':

```
SELECT *
FROM  `posts` 

+----+-----------+
| id | post_text |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | test0     |
|  2 | test1     |
|  3 | test2     |
|  4 | test3     |
|  5 | test4     |
|  6 | test5     |
|  7 | test6     |
|  8 | test7     |
|  9 | test8     |
| 10 | test9     |
| 11 | test10    |
+----+-----------+

SELECT *
FROM  `comments`

+----+------------------------------------------+---------+
| id |                 comment                  | post_id |
+----+------------------------------------------+---------+
|  1 | hello there                              |       4 |
|  2 | this is another comment on the same post |       4 |
|  3 | this is a comment on a different post    |       7 |
+----+------------------------------------------+---------+
```

I get the following:

```
SELECT posts.id, post_id, COUNT( * ) 
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN posts ON posts.id = comments.post_id
GROUP BY posts.id

+----------+---------+----------+
| posts.id | post_id | COUNT(*) |
+----------+---------+----------+
| 4        | 4       | 2        |
| 7        | 7       | 1        |
| ...      | ...     | ...      |
| ...      | ...     | ...      |
+----------+---------+----------+
```

What I'd like to do is, where the COUNT(*) is more than 1 (meaning there's more than one comment on a post), show all the matched records, instead of grouping them into one row, so it's like this:

```
+----------+---------+----------+
| posts.id | post_id | COUNT(*) |
+----------+---------+----------+
| 4        | 4       | 1        |
| 4        | 4       | 1        |
| 7        | 7       | 1        |
| ...      | ...     | ...      |
| ...      | ...     | ...      |
+----------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Just drop the `count` and the `group by`. If you still want to show the number of comments, then change `count(*)` to `(select count(1) from comments where post_id = posts.id) as comment_count`

Comment: Oh cool, thanks man. I guess I overlooked the meaning of 'GROUP BY'

Answer (score 1):

If you drop the `count` and the `group by`, you can select all the records. In order to still show the number of comments per post, then you can use a correlated subquery.

Also, I would assume that you don't really want to show both `posts.id` and `post_id` since they are the same value, so the following query should be more like your intent:

```
select posts.id as post_id, comments.id as comment_id, (select count(1) from comments where post_id = posts.id) as comment_count
from posts
left join comments on posts.id = comments.post_id
```

Here's a [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f303/7).

Comment: I found a problem - when I echo out the SQL with PHP it duplicates the values (post_id: 4), when I only wanted it printed once

Comment: @user1228907 your example of what the output should look like includes `post_id: 4` twice?

Comment: Well really I don't want it to echo out twice, but it's so I can use it to order the comments by latest comment posted (using a timestamp column I've excluded from the comments table)

Comment: It sounds like you might need to redo your PHP logic then. Probably select all posts, then within a particular post view, select all its comments ordered by insert date descending or something along those lines.

Comment: I'm trying to select all the posts and order them by latest comments, but I can't do that when the COUNT(*) groups them together!

Comment: Do you still want the posts in order? Or are you really selecting the latest comments? If you alter the query to add `order by comments.id desc` (or whatever timestamp column you're using) that would accomplish the latter. Otherwise `order by posts.id, comments.id desc` might be what you're looking for. Either way, though, you should get `posts.id` repeated for the number of associated comments. You might need to filter that out in your PHP.

Comment: Adding 'order by...' still doesn't show the latest comment since it's grouped in the COUNT(*) part :(

Comment: I'll try the PHP filter you mentioned

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028093/mysql-order-posts-by-most-recent-comment-or-last-posted

Comment: The question above is the solution!