# order by with mysql INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

i am fetching records from two tables with inner join, but i am not getting proper result.

Here is my code :

```
   real_query = "SELECT DISTINCT user.id AS uid, user.name AS unm, user.profile_pic AS upic, user_message.message_by_id AS message_by_id
                 FROM user INNER JOIN
                      user_message
                      ON user.id = user_message.message_by_id 
                 where (user_message.message_to_id = '".$sess."' AND 
                        user_message.receiver_deleted = 'No')
                 group by user_message.id, user_message.sent_on
                 order by user_message.id DESC ";
```

The problem is, i want to echo those user names from user table, order by user_message.id but i am not getting the result as i want.

Comment: What result do you want exactly? Can you please provide more details?

Comment: i want to display only names of those users who have send message to current session user,

Comment: You have a GROUP BY clause, but no aggregating functions. This is usually a recipe for a disaster. Also, a GROUP BY clause in conjunction with a DISTINCT operator is often (but not always) non-sensical.

Comment: @Strawberry That was way to big a change to someone elses question

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hey. I was just trying to give it some semblance of legibility. The EXPLAIN EXTENDED for both queries would have been identical.

Comment: @Strawberry Yea I get that and approve of the concept. The danger is you somehow, accidentally, remove an error, or add a new one, when you make that much of a chnage

Comment: Amplifying @Strawberry's point. You're misusing the pernicious MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. Read this. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html . It'a a nightmare because it makes it really hard for other developers to tell what your intent is by looking at your query.

Comment: Similar Question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028093/mysql-order-posts-by-most-recent-comment-or-last-posted/20028142#20028142